# Why use of column alias in same select is not supported in Oracle and Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, alias

```
create table t1 (c1 integer);

select c1*3 temp, case when (temp <>3) then 1 else 0 end from t1;
```

Query fails in both Oracle and MySQL But why they doesn't support this type of queries?

I already went through the answers related to column alias. Everywhere its explained what is supported and what is not and reasoning about why not in where clause. But question is about why its not supported in select clause.

Answer (score 2):

An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a different name. You can use the alias in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, or `HAVING` clauses to refer to the column:

```
SELECT SQRT(a*b) AS root FROM tbl_name
  GROUP BY root HAVING root > 0;

SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_name
  GROUP BY id HAVING cnt > 0;

SELECT id AS 'Customer identity' FROM tbl_name;
```

Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a `WHERE` clause. This restriction is imposed because when the `WHERE` clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined. For example, the following query is illegal:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_name
  WHERE cnt > 0 GROUP BY id;
```

The `WHERE` clause determines which rows should be included in the `GROUP BY` clause, but it refers to the alias of a column value that is not known until after the rows have been selected, and grouped by the `GROUP BY`.

In the select list of a query, a quoted column alias can be specified using identifier or string quoting characters:

```
SELECT 1 AS `one`, 2 AS 'two';
```

Elsewhere in the statement, quoted references to the alias must use identifier quoting or the reference is treated as a string literal. For example, this statement groups by the values in column id, referenced using the alias `a`:

```
SELECT id AS 'a', COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_name
  GROUP BY `a`;
```

But this statement groups by the literal string 'a' and will not work as expected:

```
SELECT id AS 'a', COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_name
  GROUP BY 'a';
```

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/problems-with-alias.html

Comment: I don't know how it will be for MySQL, but for Oracle `SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_name
  GROUP BY id HAVING cnt > 0;` is not valid. Aliases could be used only in `ORDER BY` clause. As well as this expression is not valid in Oracle - `SELECT 1 AS 'one', 2 AS 'two';`

Comment: I just checked - it is true for MySQL, nor for Oracle

Comment: Standard SQL doesn't allow using an alias in `WHERE`/`GROUP BY`/`HAVING`, only in `ORDER BY`. This is based on the logical evaluation of a SELEECT which is FROM->WHERE->GROUP BY->HAVING->SELECT->ORDER BY

Comment: I already went through the answers related to column alias and the link shared. Everywhere its explained what is supported and what is not and reasoning about why not in where clause. But question is about why not in select clause.

Comment: @sandippawar1412 because you can only CREATE alias in SELECT and then use in ORDER BY. Because db have no idea what 'temp' is when doing select.

Comment: `id AS 'a'` is invalid standard SQL and will fail in Oracle. Single quotes are for string literals, not for identifiers

Answer (score 1):

You can't use aliases in any sections except `ORDER BY` (in Oracle)

So you can do either:

```
select c1*3 temp, case when (c1*3 <>3) then 1 else 0 end from t1;
```

Or:

```
select temp, case when (temp <>3) then 1 else 0 end 
from (
select c1*3 temp from t1);
```